# Talking to my supervisor about leaving the lab

Tags: phd

My supervisor is really toxic. She has been yelling at me for every lab meeting and getting angrier by the day, due to which I am subjected to immense anxiety and panic attacks mad severe depression. So much so that I have decided to leave the project after 3 years of work.  I know that she is going to get really angry after getting to know this. How can I put forth the mental health issues in a way that she is at least a little bit convinced by my reason to leave?

Comment: This sounds like an awful situation. I'm very sorry! Does your department have an academic who is in charge of the PhD programme? Or do you have a "mentor" (someone who is neither involved in your research nor in the assessment of your work). Either of those may be able to advise.

Comment: Do you think it is better that I inform her first rather than getting a third party involved without her knowledge?

Comment: This very much is situation-dependent. But if you believe that she would just "get really angry" in such a conversation and that this would further negatively affect your mental health, I would advise to get third-party support first.

Comment: Do you need her approval to quit? I don't think there is any way to communicate to a toxic person that you are leaving (and the reason is her) in a way that she will not be angry. But it also matters little.

Comment: I don't need her approval. I am employed at the university hospital so even if I tell her that I quit it will be sufficient ideally as my contract is coming to an end in January. This discussion would be to let them know that there isn't a need to extend my contract further.

Comment: There are people who will not be reasoned with. They will not be convinced. They do not negotiate. Understand one thing: Unless you endangered lives (in which case, I could see a case for yelling), and I assume it's not, it is not your fault. Period. In the end, it's just yelling and you are leaving. Don't give her control over you by discussing your exit. You have decided. That's your decision to make, she has no say in that. Understand: you have decided. If she catches you and yells, you have decided. Think: "You have no power here". But if you don't have to tell her, why bother?

Comment: You shouldn't care if she gets angry. Also I think you don't need to give her a detailed explanation or even convincing if you don't want. If you already decided to leave, just follow the administrative process (which often does not require you to make contact with her) to finish your contract/project through the school/employer.

Remember that your health is first, and no profesional goal or the opinion of anyone should comprimise that. She was in a position of power before. Now that you are leaving she has no more power over you. Don't worry and take care of yourself.

Comment: All of the suggestions help a lot! Thank you all!